# How to populate a deck class with instances of a card class? c++

Tags: c++, class

I have a program for which I have created a simple card class.  How can I create and populate a deck of playing cards?

Comment: Interesting question - covers algorithms for populating containers, re-use/re-purposing of existing classes, etc..

Answer (score 3):

If you have a class for `card` simply create a class for `deck` which among other things contains a data structure (such as `std::vector` or an array) to contain the `card` objects. Then implement functions such as `deal` , `shuffle` etc or whatever you feel appropriate.

To populate your deck, you could use an `add_card` function. You can then use this to loop over all suits and values to create a card of each distinct suit/value type and add it to your deck. Alternatively (or additionally), you could do this in the `deck` constructor, but having an `add_card` function will allow your deck to model different types of decks such as individual card `hands` or multiple deck games such as casino blackjack for example.

If you use a container from the standard C++ library that supports random access iterators, you could make use of the `std::random_shuffle` function to shuffle your `deck`

EDIT: updated to incorporate some of the points raised in comments

Comment: for dealing would need `hand` classes as well .. ;)

Comment: I am so much worried about the functions of the deck class i am more simply wondering as how to populate each card number (2-A) and suit

Comment: @slashmais no. Each `hand` holds a `deck`, so `deal`ing just means "separate n `deck`s of size k from this `deck` and return them" :-)

Comment: @DonRigatone But you said you already have a card class? surely the number and suit are member variables of the card class??

Comment: they are indeed both members of the class however I am wondering how to implement 52 instances of them like a deck of cards

Comment: @DonRigatone Well loop over each suit, then loop over each card type and create one of each. Then for example you can have a deck::add_card function and add each card to the deck. Alternatively you could create them all in the constructor of the deck but for more flexibility it might be better to allow the addition through a function (in case your requirements change later - for example if you modelled a multi-deck game of blackjack). Probably less efficient but it depends on your needs. For the container, consider std::stack, and consider using the std::random_shuffle as a start

Comment: @DonRigatone what's wrong with looping over suit and value and instantiating in the `deque` class' constructor?

Comment: @mathematician1975: would be useful to expand your answer with your response in the comments, e.g. give general solution and apply to the OP's specific need

Comment: @slashmais The OPs specific need is not overly specific, but I take your point and have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is to extend mathematician1975's answer with an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <array> //needs c++11 support

enum CARDSUIT { Spades, Hearts, Diamonds, Clubs };
typedef std::pair< int, int > Card;
template< class T, size_t N> struct DECK : public std::array< T, N> 
{
    void shuffle()
    {
        //see here for example:
        // http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/
    }
};
typedef DECK<Card, 52> StandardDeck;

int main()
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    StandardDeck deck;

    for (i=Spades; i<=Clubs; i++)
        for (j=0; j<13; j++)
                deck[j + (i*13)] = Card(i,j);

    for (i=0; i<(int)deck.size(); i++) 
        std::cout << deck[i].first << " " << deck[i].second << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is a conversion from an int to a card such that each number from 0-51 yields a unique card. It doesn't really matter how, as long as they are all unique.

Then you can create a deck of cards from each number in a loop, possibly into a vector, and you can perform std::random_shuffle to shuffle a deck.

If you want your deck of cards to remain "generic" as to what game is going to be played then do not make features member functions of the card but "free" functions. e.g. the ace of spades may outrank the 7 of spades at Bridge but that is a feature of Bridge (and Whist related games), not of cards in general. Similarly a card, or deck, has no concept of "trumps".

You might want a special card option for a joker. Of course games that don't use jokers wouldn't allow one of these in the deck.